# PostgreSQL: Suitable ID to uniquely identify client socket connection

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on an application which needs to track the connection status of TCP sockets to a PostgreSQL database instance.  I'm looking for a suitable ID which can uniquely identify a particular socket connection amongst all the others.  Ideally this ID will have the following properties:

- The ID will not change while the particular socket is connected
- Different sockets from different hosts to the PostgreSQL server will have different IDs
- Multiple sockets from the same host and username connected to the same database (e.g. a connection pool) will each have different IDs
- If a socket disconnects, then after a while reconnects from the same host and username to the same database, it will have a different ID

Looking at the PostgreSQL documentation, I see that there is a notion of a "process ID", which looks to be different for each socket connection to a single database instance.  However, I'm a little confused as to whether this is the actual OS process ID of the PostgreSQL server itself, or whether this is a PostgreSQL construct identifying a particular socket.  I see there is also a "session ID" which looks to be derived from the "process start time and the process ID" (according to the [documentation on logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#id-1.6.6.11.5.2.10.1.3)) which may or may not work depending on what the process ID actually is.

My questions are:

1. Would the process ID or session ID be a suitable unique identifier for a connected socket?
2. If not, is there another ID that I could use that can act as a unique identifier, or would I need to derive one from the remote host and port?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every PostgreSQL database connection has a *backend process* on the database server, which processes the SQL statements for that connection. The process ID of that backend process can therefore uniquely identify a certain database session, and that is what is used as identifier for a client connection in PostgreSQL. You can get the process ID for the current session with the `pg_backend_pid()` function.

Note that over the course of time, process IDs can be reused. So if you are looking for a globally unique identifier for a database session, you may want to add the timestamp at which the connection was established. You can use the following query to get both for the current database session:

```
SELECT pid, backend_start
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pid = pg_backend_pid();
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the explanation.